# What is the probability of two random elements from two lists are equal? (formal proof)

Tags: probability, birthday, collision-detection

Suppose $L_1$ and $L_2$ are the lists of random uniform elements with sizes $m$. The elements are from $\{0,1\}^{n}$, e.g. the binary vector in $F_2^n$. What is the probability that $x_1 \in L_1$ and $x_2 \in L_2$ such that $x_1 = x_2$ ?

I need a formal proof for it. My idea is as followed:
Let $X=a$($Y=b$) be the random variable that take element $a$(b) from the list, then $P(X=a, Y=b)=\frac{1}{m^{2}}$. We need to calculate the probability $P(X=Y)$. We use $P(X=Y) = \sum_{a \in L_1, b\in L_2} P(a==b|X=a,Y=b) P(X=a, Y=b)$. The $P(a=b|X=a, Y=b)$ means the probability that $a$ is equal to $b$ under the condition that we take element $a(b)$ from $L_1(L_2)$, then what is this probability? Or what is the alternative proof?

Answer (score 1):

No, $P(X=Y)=\frac 1{2^n}$ because there is only one value from each list being considered.  You would sum over the possible values of $X$ and $Y$ if you want the expected number of matches between the two lists and get $\frac {m^2}{2^n}$ for that answer.

Comment: Can you give me more detailed proof that $P(X=Y) = \frac{1}{2^n}$? Intuitively, given an element $a \in \{0,1\}^{n}$,  and we randomly select another element $b$ from $F_q^n$, the probability of $P(a==b) $ indeed is $\frac{1}{2^n}$. However, the problem  here seems different since we have given the fixed elements $a,b$, and we want to know the $P(a==b)$?

Comment: It is correct as long as at least one of $a,b$ is randomly selected from the bit strings.  If there is a bias in the bit strings that are in your lists it will not be correct.